# Run JS using Qt QML engine

Tags: qt, qml

I use the QtQML module for frontends. Can I use the embedded JS engine for other purposes like implementing a scripting interface for my app?

To achieve the above I guess I would have to dynamically laod *.js files and use its functions, but how?

Comment: You can use the JS Engine for whatever you want. You can include seperate *.js files and define/call functions in these files. You can even access QML objects in this *.js files if you include them in your QML files.

Comment: include is statically at component creation. what I want to achieve is to dynamically load js files and call its functions.

Comment: One way to achive that is (!!! EVIL !!!) the eval function. With eval you can parse and execute your *js files. But as mentioned, the use of the eval function is HIGHLY discouraged.

Comment: using QML as a JS engine is like hammering nails with a microscope, it exists for slightly different purposes. you should use some kind of library that was created specifically for what you need, like [mujs](https://mujs.com/), [Duktape](https://duktape.org/) or another one. Qt has its oun JS engine that you can use through [QJSEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html)

Comment: Sure but it is there anyway. If it is possible it comes at nearly zero cost.

Comment: @JürgenLutz Why do you say that `eval` is *highly discouraged*?

Comment: As the ***folibis***  mentioned, you can use the [`QJSEngine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#importModule), and you can also access your [`QQmlEngine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#evaluate) on the *C++* side to [`import`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#importModule) modules or [`evaluate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#evaluate) scripts.

Comment: eval can be a security hole. Google for it. you will find a bunch of pages explaining the issues with it (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)